# Next and previous buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are libraries etc that I could use to get this sorted but Im almost there with my code.

A little about the code and what it's trying to do. I have a mysql table where there are various news articles and grouped in categories of news.

I have managed to get a forward button working. So it looks for the next news article that is in the same category. This works and the code is below.

```
//Gets the next story from the same story type in line. 
$query= "SELECT * FROM news WHERE storytype2 = '$storytype2' AND id > '$currentid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_results > 0){ 
   echo "<td width=\"20%\"align=\"right\"><a href=\"news.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><img title=\"Next News\" src=\"webImg/forwardarrow.png\"/></a></td></tr>";
}else{
   echo "<td width=\"20%\"align=\"right\"></td></tr>";
}
//End of the next button
```

However, when I try do the same for the previous button. All I ever seem to get back is the first id of that category regardless of where my iteration is. For example, if I am on news article 10 and try to go to previous one which say has an id of 7 it will automatically show the first news article within that category, say id 4.

Below is the code.

```
//Gets the next story from the same story type in line. 
$query= "SELECT * FROM news WHERE storytype2 = '$storytype2' AND id < '$currentid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_results > 0){ 
   echo "<td width=\"20%\"align=\"left\"><a href=\"news.php?id=".$row['id']."\"><img title=\"Previous News\" src=\"webImg/backarrow.png\"/></a></td>";        
}else{
   echo "<td width=\"20%\"align=\"left\"></td>";
}
//End of the next button
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: use `$query= "SELECT * FROM news WHERE storytype2 = '$storytype2' AND id < '$currentid' order by id desc limit 1";`

Comment: They should both point to the same page.  Why do you need one page with a query < id and another > id?  That's so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your queries is correct. Your "Next" code selects *any* row whose ID is higher than the current, not necessarily the next one; if you get the next one, it's just by accident.

You should use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to control which row is selected:

Next:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE storytype2 = '$storytype2' AND id > '$currentid'
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Previous:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news 
WHERE storytype2 = '$storytype2' AND id < '$currentid'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, I don't think you can assume that the first row of your queries will be the ID you're looking for. Ordering by ID first will probably solve your problem; you can also limit your query to one row, since it's the only one you're looking at. Something like the following would probably solve your problem (where `x` is $storytype2 and `y` is $currentid:

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE storytype2 = x
 AND id < y
ORDER BY id DESC /* <-- THIS */
LIMIT 1
```

Use `ORDER BY id ASC` for the other case.
Note that the MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear, if it hasn't yet. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Note also that you are inserting a variable into SQL code directly, which is never a good idea. I hope you have some good input checks on your variables.

Let's look at the PDO way to get the previous article ID:

```
$dbh = new PDO(..);
// Use ? where dynamic input will come
$sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM news
  WHERE storytype2 = ?
  AND id < ?
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1');

// Fill the ? safely with PDO's execute function
$sql->execute(array($storytype2, $currentid));
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result && isset($result['id'])) {
   // Process previous ID
}
```